# Prevent dataGridView.ReadOnly setting from overriding DataGridViewColumn.ReadOnly setting

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010, datagridviewcolumn

I have a datagridview added to my form via the designer, some of the columns in it has their read-only state set to true.

The problem is when I try to toggle the datagridviews read-only state the columns read-only state also changes. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: There is barely any code, I have created the datagridview from the designer & added the columns via the designer too. And at runtime I set `datagridview1.ReadOnly = True` and after a certain condition I set it back to `False`. Then the columns that I have previously set to be read-only also becomes false.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

Instead of preventing from *changing* the *read-only state*,after the *filling datagridview*, u should write code to ensure that the columns are in *read-only state*.
**Example:**

```
'Clear previous DataGridView DataSource
DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing

'Get the datasource for datagridview
DataGridView1.DataSource = objDataSet.Tables(0)

'Make sure the columns are read-only 
DataGridView1.Columns(0).ReadOnly = True
DataGridView1.Columns(1).ReadOnly = True
```

Hope, this help.